# RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I am attempting to launch an activity after the screen is unlocked and am getting the error log below. I looked at the other posts regarding my issue but now of them solved my problem

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.me.phone.Receive: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.me.phone.Receive
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2239)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Mainifest

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_USER_PRESENT" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.me.phone.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".Recieve" >
            <intent-filter
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="false" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Reciever

```
    package com.me.phone;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Recieve extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Intent activity = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        activity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(activity);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that "Receive" is spelled two different ways in your example?

From the exception:

```
...java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.me.phone.Receive
```

From the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".Recieve" >
```

Comment: Well there I go. I need to start using an IDE with spell check haha